# Ajuda com script javascript

Tags: javascript

Preciso de uma mãozinha aqui !

```
<script>
  window.onload = function() {
    var oTextbox = document.getElementById('myTextBox');
    for (var i = 0; i < document.oTextbox.length; i++) {
        document.oTextbox[i].onfocus = function() {
            oTextbox.value = this.alt;
        };

    for (var i = 0; i < document.images.length; i++) {
        document.images[i].onclick = function() {
            oTextbox.value = this.alt;
        };
    }
};
</script>
```

peguei este script aqui mesmo no stack em [link do script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11188841/click-on-image-and-change-a-text) , e uso com um input e varias imagens funciona perfeitamente ! mas ao usar o script php em foreach, o mesmo cria varios inputs mas todos com o mesmo nome, imagino que seja possivel ao clicar ou setar on focus no input e clicar na imagen o mesmo possa, passar os valores pra outro campo selecionado!

meu foreach!

```
<?php foreach($data["category"] as $categ):?>
<label><?=$categ->name;?></label>
 <input type="text" name="img_ent" id="myTextBox" value="Imagen entrada" 
 class="form-control" placeholder="Imagen Entrada">
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Explicando melhor !

Eu peguei o script que eu ao clicar na imagen ele automaticamente ja coloca o nome da imagen no input ok,ate ai tudo bem funciona, o que fiz foi  fazer o input em loop foreach com php, dae tudo bem tambem, ele gera varios inputs de acordo com minha database exemplo 5 ... dae vem o problema ao gerar estes 5 inputs eu clico na imagen e ele faz exatamente o que faz sem o loop, ele apenas adiciona o texto no primeiro input mesmo que eu clique no segundo input ele adiciona ao primeiro do mesmo jeito! dae pensei que tal fazer on focus os outros inputs pois dae ao clicar no input e selecionar clicando na imagen ele passasse os valores para o outro input. não imagino se é possivel...

Comment: Como você está aplicando o `foreach` no seu código?

Comment: Há um problema nesse código: o primeiro `for` faz contagem de IDs, o que é uma má pratica em HTML. Um ID deve ser único na página, portanto, nem deveria ser contado. Outra coisa é que a sua pergunta não explica com clareza o que vc deseja e faz confusão: "_clicar ou setar on focus no input e clicar na imagen o mesmo possa, passar os valores pra outro campo selecionado_"...

Comment: explicando mlehor pergunta reformulada!

Comment: como eu disse eu clico em uma imagen ele vai pro input primeiro mas se eu clico no input 2 ao invez de ir para o segundo ele manda o texto pro primeiro

Comment: var oTextbox = document.getElementById('myTextBox'); acredito que aqui devia ter um +i pois ao fazer em loop pelo php os valores dos inpts se repetem!

Comment: eu tenho 200 imagens  a quantidade de imagen nao inporta o que inporta e o input no caso!

Comment: acredito que ue deva fazer isso 
var first = document.getElementById("textbox1").value;
 var second = document.getElementById("textbox2").value;

Comment: Se não me engano ao clicar no input ele tem o foco mas se depois clicar em outra coisa esse input perde o foco. O melhor a fazer é postar o código todo pra gente poder testar

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo O problema é que a pergunta tem um texto enorme e não diz nada. É uma confusão de palavras "clico naquilo, perde o foco naquilo outro, clica imagem, clico no input, joga o valor pra lá e pra cá"... tive que votar pra fechar por falta de clareza

Comment: Muito obvio, o que não está obvio é `pois dae ao clicar no input e selecionar clicando na imagen `

Comment: @dvd a pergunta é clara, vc q tá com sono e vendo coisas :D

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo rsrs... clara como água.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/carloscoelho/5xm84f70/2/

Answer (score 2):

O que você está querendo fazer não dá certo.

1. Com ids dos inputs **iguais**, sempre vai cair no primeiro input
2. Com ids dos inputs **diferentes**, ao final do loop, sempre vai cair no ultimo input

### Sugestões

**Com javascript:**

No php gere os ids dos inputs com numero sequencial ao final do valor ex:

`id="myTextBox0"` `id="myTextBox1"` `id="myTextBox2"` etc...

em cada tag img acrescente o evento com a respectiva numeração no valor do id

`onclick="document.getElementById('myTextBox0').value=this.alt"`

`onclick="document.getElementById('myTextBox1').value=this.alt"`

Resultado

```html
<input type="text" name="Example" id="myTextBox0"/>
<input type="text" name="Example" id="myTextBox1"/>
<input type="text" name="Example" id="myTextBox2"/>
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS0ejnQio1K4_9rPAg4gccOyubd9MDsm9EHqFPSj775hxt3NAW2" alt="primary image" onclick="document.getElementById('myTextBox0').value=this.alt" width="100"/>
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQrWio0j91C833kB_x-UeRsqc52Ft2TJGDC-YTjyEYb8k7X-PpH" alt="second image" onclick="document.getElementById('myTextBox1').value=this.alt" width="100"/>
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRBUDSuBgsJFMgAnDk0qCNvlJtXcEVrqsaH7nXCiCtcUEVMMTT_Jg" alt="third image" onclick="document.getElementById('myTextBox2').value=this.alt" width="100"/>
```

**Com Jquery**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.clickable').click(function(){
    var idimg = $(this).attr('id');
    document.getElementById('myTextBox'+idimg).value = this.alt;
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="Example" id="myTextBox0" />
<input type="text" name="Example" id="myTextBox1" />
<input type="text" name="Example" id="myTextBox2" />
<img id="0" class="clickable" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS0ejnQio1K4_9rPAg4gccOyubd9MDsm9EHqFPSj775hxt3NAW2" alt="primary image" width="100" />
<img id="1" class="clickable" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQrWio0j91C833kB_x-UeRsqc52Ft2TJGDC-YTjyEYb8k7X-PpH" alt="second image" width="100" />
<img id="2" class="clickable" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRBUDSuBgsJFMgAnDk0qCNvlJtXcEVrqsaH7nXCiCtcUEVMMTT_Jg" alt="third image" width="100" />
```

Comment: +1 por utilizar dogues nas imagens :P